# almacenar el resultado ajax de una función en otra

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Dentro mi función **descargarProformas** quiero almacenar en una variable el resultado de la función **obtenerAcuerdos**, la cual tiene un response de ajax. Intenté hacer un callback, pero al momento de hacer el ***console.log(listaAcuerdos);*** me muestra **undefined**.

Esta es la función **descargarProformas**

```js
function descargarProformas(){
    var idEmpresa = $('#selectEmpresa').val();
    var listaAcuerdos;
    obtenerAcuerdos(idEmpresa, function(data){
        listaAcuerdos = data;
    });    
    console.log(listaAcuerdos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y esta es la función de la cual quiero obtener el resultado del ajax

```js
function obtenerAcuerdos(idEmpresa, callback){
    var datos = {
        'opcion' : 'obtenerAcuerdos',
        'idEmpresa' : idEmpresa
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controlador/proformas.controlador.php',
        type:'POST',
        data : datos,
        cache:false,
        success: function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de ejecutar ajax puede asignar una variable y retornarla

```
function descargar () {
    var listaAcuerdos = obtenerAcuerdos(idEmpresa);
}

function obtenerAcuerdos(idEmpresa) {
    var data;
    //Puedes remplazar ajax por esta forma
    $.post('../controlador/proformas.controlador.php', datos).then((response) => {
         data = JSON.parse(response);
    }, (fail) => {});
    return data;
}
```